# Setting alignment in verticalpanel - gwt

Tags: gwt, alignment

I am trying to set the align property in vertical panel in GWT like this:

```
vpanel = new VerticalPanel();
vPanel.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_LEFT);
```

and then adding children which gives me a table like this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td align="left"></td></tr>
<tr><td align="left"></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

But what I want is

```
<table align="left">
<tbody>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I know it's a stupid question but I am stuck with browser compatibility issue and only the HTML specified fixes issue on all browsers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the underlying element of a widget and set an attribute to it using `getElement().setAttribute(..)` for instance :

```
VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
panel.getElement().setAttribute("align", "left");
RootPanel.get().add(panel);
```